# Running an MLFlow server in --artifacts-only mode

Tags: python, mlflow, artifacts

when Running an MLFlow server in --artifacts-only mode,there is the commond:
`mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5001 --serve-artifacts --artifacts-destination hdfs://hdfapathxxxx --artifacts-only`
Then i used the method to load artifacts by:

```
import os
import mlflow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Running mlflow_tracking.py")

    mlflow.set_tracking_uri("http://xxx:5001/")

    with mlflow.start_run():
        if not os.path.exists("outputs"):
            os.makedirs("outputs")
        with open("outputs/test.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("hello world!")
        mlflow.log_artifacts(local_dir="outputs")
```

but,there is something wrong, the error info is :
mlflow.exceptions.MlflowException: API request to http://xxxx:5001/api/2.0/mlflow/runs/create failed with exception HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxxx', port=5001): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/mlflow/runs/create (Caused by ResponseError('too many 503 error responses'))

of course, there is nothing in mlflow web ui.
please help me，Is there an error in my usage method？

I change the method of loading artifacts :MlflowClient().log_artifacts(run_id = "xx",local_dir="outputs")
but,Still reporting an error